# How one parameter is used by two function simultaneously

Tags: haskell

I am reading about applicative functors and found such line:

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5
```

It outputs 508.

How 5 could be used by (+3) and (*100) at the same time?
Why don't we need to pass two 5's as a parameters like:

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5 5
```

Comment: That's the idea of the `<*>` operator for functions.

Comment: I read <*>'s types and it seems that both (+3) and (*100) each needs separate argument

Comment: You have to check how [`instance Applicative ((->) a)` for `<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%3C%2A%3E#GHC.Base.html#Applicative) is implemented.

Comment: @BulatM. yes, both (+3) and (*100) each indeed need separate argument, and `<*>` is supplying it to them. it's just how it's defined: `(f <*> g) x = f x $ g x`. It's just a given. Then, your expression is actually parenthesized as `(((+) <$> (+3)) <*> (*100)) 5` which by substituting the arguments for the parameters gives us `((+) <$> (+3)) 5 $ (*100) 5` = `((+) . (+3)) 5 (5*100) = (+) (5+3) (5*100)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `(->) a` applicative instance, we find:

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
    liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
```

So, `x` is passed to both `f` and `g` by definition.

Comment: Could you please show how f g x correspond to values in my expression?

Comment: @Bulat M. `(+) <$> (+3)` is `f`, `(*100)` is `g` and `5` is `x`

Comment: @Bulat you probably want to read chapter 11 of [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to unbox it. We start with

```
e = ((+) <$> (+3)) <*> (*100)
```

(note that I left out the `$ 5`). The Applicative Functor whose `<$>` and `<*>` we are using here is the Function type `(->)` (partially applied to, I guess, `Integer`). Here, the meaning of `<$>` and `<*>` is as follows:

```
f <$> g = \y -> f (g y)
g <*> h = \x -> g x (h x)
```

We can plug that in into the term in the first line and get

```
e = \x -> (\y -> (+) ((+3) y)) x ((*100) x
```

There are a few simplifications that we can do to this term:

```
e = \x -> (x+3) + (x*100)
```

So if this function is the value of `(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100)`, then it should no longer be surprising that applying this to `5` gives

```
e 5 = (5+3) + (5*100) = 508
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you first have to understand how a function can be a functor. Think about a function like a container which reveals it's content only when you feed it with a parameter. In other words we only get to know it's content when this applicative functor (function) gets invoked with a parameter. So the type of this function would be say `r -> a` on two different types. However for functors we can only take an effect on a single type. So applicative functors are partially applied types just like the functor instance of `Either` type. We are interested in the output of the function so our applicative functor becomes `(->) r` in prefix notation. By remembering that `<$>` is the infix form of `fmap`

`(+3) <$> (*2) $ 4` would result `11`. `4` is applied to our functor `(*2)` and the result (which is the value in the applicative functor context) gets mapped with `(+3)`.

However in our case we are `fmap`ing `(+)` to `(+3)`. To make it clearer lets rephrase the functions in lambda form.

`(+) = \w x -> w + x` and `(+3) = \y -> y + 3`.

then `(+) <$> (+3)` by partially applying `\y -> y + 3` in the place of `w` our `fmap` applied applicative functor becomes `\y x -> (y + 3) + x`.

Now here comes the applicative operator `<*>`. As mentioned in previous answers it is of definition `g <*> h = \x -> g x (h x)` which takes a two parameter function `g` and partially applies `g`'s second parameter with it's second parameter function `h`. Now our operation looks like

`(\y x -> (y + 3) + x) <*> (*100)` which can be rephrased as;
`(\y x -> (y + 3) + x) <*> (\z -> z*100)` which means now we have to partially apply `\z -> z*100` to `x` and our function becomes `\y z -> (y + 3) + (z*100)`.

Finally the applicative operator returns us a function which takes a single parameter and applies it to both parameters of the above two parameter function. So

`\x -> (\y z -> (y + 3) + (z*100)) x x`